# $3\times 3$ Matrix Completion

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, matrix-completion

Consider the following matrix:

$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}
       3 & 1 & x \\
       2 & 0 & 1 \\
       y & 4 & 1
     \end{bmatrix}.
$$

> I want to find complex numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $M^{-1}$ exist and is a 2-band matrix.

I know that when the determinant for a square matrix is not equal to zero, the inverse for that matrix does exist. We observe that

$$
\det(M)\not=0 \iff \begin{vmatrix}
       3 & 1 & x \\
       2 & 0 & 1 \\
       y & 4 & 1
     \end{vmatrix}\not=0 \iff 8x+y\not=14. \tag{1}
$$

However, the inverse of matrix $M$ is (assuming (1)) equal to

$$
\dfrac{1}{8 x+y-14}\begin{bmatrix}
-4 & 4 x-1 & 1\\
y-2 & 3-x y & 2 x-3\\
8 & y-12 & -2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So, $M^{-1}$ is a 2-band matrix iff 
$$
y\not=2,12 \\ 
x\not=1/4,3/2 \tag{2}\\
xy\not=3 
$$ 
and therefore we can conclude that $M^{-1}$ exist and is a 2-band matrix iff (1) and (2) holds.

> My question is: Is this method correct? If so, what can we say about the uniqueness of the solution?

---

**Edit**:

a matrix $A$ is called a $k$-band matrix if $a_{ij}=0$ for $|i-j|>k$.

Comment: From what I can tell a 2 band matrix is one which has only 2 diagonals with nonzero elements on it. So it seems that there are no values of $x,y$ such that there are 2 diagonals consisting completely of zero values.

Comment: What is a $2$-band matrix??

Comment: @NickR a matrix $A$ is called a $k$-band matrix if $a_{ij}=0$ for $|i-j|>k$. so here, $M^{-1}$ is called a 2-band matrix if $m_{ij}=0$ for $|i-j|>2$, which means $m_{ij}\not=0$ for all $i,j\in{1,2,3}$, right? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @gerw see edit.

Comment: From this definition follows that a 3x3 matrix is always a 2-band matrix, because |i-j|<=2, for all i=1,2,3, j=1,2,3

Comment: @miracle173 True, but the matrix entries $a_{ij}$ for all $i,j$ have to be nonzero entries right?

Comment: No. You (typically) only want $|i-j| > k \; \Rightarrow\; a_{ij} = 0$ and not $|i-j| > k \; \Leftrightarrow\; a_{ij} = 0$.

Comment: @gerw So, condition (2) is unnecessary and (1) is sufficient to conclude that $M^{-1}$ exist and is a 2-band?

Comment: Yes, I would think so.